# Not able to view Token Transfers Using Infura and Web3?

Tags: tokens, web3.py, infura

I am trying to get insight into token transactions for various smart contracts using infura and web.py. The following snippet of code I thought should return me transactions for that contract, but I'm getting the error message below instead. Is there an error in my code or can you not use infura to query contract events?

```
    web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/your-personal-number"))

con_abi ='[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pay","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"weiBalance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"weiValue","type":"uint256"},{"name":"rate","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenEquivalent","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalWeiReceived","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalTokenSold","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"initialSupply","type":"uint256"},{"name":"tokenName","type":"string"},{"name":"tokenSymbol","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Burn","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"receiver","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Withdrawal","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"backer","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"weiAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"token","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Selfdrop","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"receiver","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"weiAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"OverSoftCap","type":"event"}]'
contractAddr = web3.eth.contract(address='0x042969AcfA0a586A939652612458A2387Ab0073a',abi=con_abi)

transferEvent = contractAddr.eventFilter('Transfer', {'fromBlock': 0,'toBlock': 'latest'})
```

Error message:

```
HTTPError: 405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url: https://mainnet.infura.io/your-personal-number
```

FYI-  I did attempt replacing the [your personal] key with both the api key and api secret.